# Enable Verbose mode for Laravel 4 Queue Listener

Tags: php, queue, laravel, laravel-4

When running the Listener via `php artisan queue:listen`, its pretty quiet even though the Worker may be echoing something.

**Question:** How do you enable those echos to be displayed on the screen, similar to how `php artisan queue:work` does it?

Answer (score 9):

I don't believe that listen is meant to have any output, and I can't see anything in the [ListenCommand](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/ListenCommand.php) that would suggest there's any more output to give.  However, when you ask artisan for help it suggests `--verbose (-v)` which you could give a try?

```
php artisan queue:listen -v
```

My understanding of listen is that it is designed to be run as a background service, essentially calling `queue:work` repeatedly.  If you wanted to test that a worker is working you'd just call `queue:work` yourself.  You probably want to look at adding some [logging](http://four.laravel.com/docs/errors#logging) to your code, and you'll be able to look in the log files then.

---

> ```
> $ php artisan help queue:listen
>
> Usage:
>  queue:listen [--queue[="..."]] [--delay[="..."]] [--memory[="..."]] [--timeout[="..."]] [connection]
>
> Arguments:
>  connection            The name of connection
>
> Options:
>  --queue               The queue to listen on
>  --delay               Amount of time to delay failed jobs (default: 0)
>  --memory              The memory limit in megabytes (default: 128)
>  --timeout             Seconds a job may run before timing out (default: 60)
>  --help (-h)           Display this help message.
>  --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message.
>  --verbose (-v)        Increase verbosity of messages.
>  --version (-V)        Display this application version.
>  --ansi                Force ANSI output.
>  --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output.
>  --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question.
>  --env                 The environment the command should run under.>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan queue:listen` now does render the worker output to the console when run. No verbose mode needed.

Comment: In which version of Laravel? The question is specifically about Laravel 4 and this is definitely not the case in Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Listen is very quiet.  Personally, I use OS X / Linux and run the following in another terminal window to monitor the output.

```
tail -f storage/logs/*
```